# Making WebIOPi work on Raspberry Pi 3

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, webiopi

I am working a lot with serial devices through the Internet using WebIOPi, I recently acquired a Raspberry Pi 3 because of the WiFi.

However, when I install the last version of Raspbian and WebIOPi, it doesn't work.

My html project appears in the browser and everything, but the serial devices don't respond to any command.

I don't know what is happening or what I've done wrong or if there is something different that I need to do in order to make WebIOPi work as it should.

EDIT: I saw from another question that the RPI 3 uses /dev/ttyAMA0 for the bluetooth and instead uses /dev/ttys0 as the serial port. Right now I don't see that port on my Pi.

I really need help for this, maybe what I need to do is something really simple, but I can't see what is that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this link at github](https://github.com/doublebind/raspi).  It has a patch for WebioPi that makes it work on the PI2 and PI3.  I have used it successfully on the PI2, but have not tried it on the PI3.  There is a discussion of the patch at [raspberrypi.org](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=63&t=98981)

Comment: I used that patch for my PI2, but it didn't work on my PI3. Now I am able to send and receive messages with a python script, but for some reason, I can't make it work through the html file that I have previously used with my PI2.

Comment: I forgot about this question, I found out what was happening, the problem wit the HTML was the order in which I wrote my Javascript functions. Once I changed the order, everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

If your question is about the serial on the Pi see [How-do-i-make-serial-work-on-the-raspberry-pi3](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/45571/8697)

Serial is now `/dev/serial0` but is disabled by default on the Pi3.

Comment: Now I am able to send and receive messages with a python script, but for some reason, I can't make it work through the html file that I have previously used with my PI2. I added this to `/boot/config.txt`: `enable_uart=1`, `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt`, `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt`.

Comment: @LuzA You should put additional detail as an edit in your question, not in Comments. I don't know why you use both `dtoverlay=pi3-miniuart-bt` and `dtoverlay=pi3-disable-bt` (not that I have used either). I know nothing about `WebioPi` but unless you post code or settings no one else is likely to help.